# How to load database values into table cells based on the value from from cell?

Tags: javascript, php, html

There is a purchase table, I need enter my product from the list of products i select from cell one . Based on this selection the other cells need to load current stock quantity, purchased price into other cells without reloading the page. If i reload the page it clears out the values i entered for all the rows.

Created table
Can select product

```
<table name="<?php echo $name ?>" id="<?php echo $name ?>" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
foreach ($hnames as $hn) {
    ?>
            <th>
                <?php echo $hn ?>
            </th>
            <?php
}
?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php select("p_name", $products, "id", "name");?>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" onchange=calculate_amount() value=0><br>available qty 00.000</td>
            <td><input type="text" onchange=calculate_amount() value=0><br>Last purchase price 0000</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Total</th>
            <th>0</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

   function select($name,$result,$value,$display)
    {
    ?>
    <select name="<?php echo $name?>"    id="<?php echo $name?>">
    <?php
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    ?>                
    <option value=<?php echo $r[$value]?>><?php echo $r[$display]?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to either store the information within a JSON object and reference the values from there or use AJAX to retrieve the data from the database. If you only have a couple of hundred products then the JSON method will do fine otherwise you will need to look at the AJAX method.

Comment: @jeff Worked. TY.